# Selenium: How to click on all DIVs with same class name

Tags: python, selenium

I've been working on scraping a site which has usually 10 to 12 DIVs with the same class name. When clicked on any one of these DIVs, it goes to a new page. I want to scrape data from that page and then navigate back to previous page and then click on the next div and so on.

But I can't figure out that when I come back to the previous page how can I click on the next div?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
matches = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('ipo-CompetitionBase ')
index = 0
while index <= len(matches):
    matches[index].click()
    browser.back()
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with that is that you cannot simply find all the `div`s and click them one by one because when you get back to the previous page the elements you've previously found already became "stale" and you need to "re-find" them.

I'd maintain an *index* of a current `div` element I'm clicking and, every time I'd get back to the main page, I would click the `div` element at the index + 1 position. Continue that until you've exhausted all the `div` elements on the main page.

More like a pseudo-code:

```
index = 0
while True:
   divs = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('className')

   try: 
       divs[index].click()
   except IndexError:
       break  # no more elements, exit the loop

   # do smth
   # ...

   browser.back()

   index += 1
```

Comment: How exactly can I loop through all the DIVs? 
-->browser.find_elements_by_class_name('className')

find_elements_by_class_name returns all the DIVs it found, in the form of array. But the problem is that when I come back from the page I just scraped, how can I proceed to next DIV. Loop doesn't quite seem to work for me.

Comment: @abhanan93 alright, updated with a sample code. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @alecxa. But unfortunately when I come back to the previous after scraping the first div, I encounter this error.

StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

Comment: @abhanan93 that's what should not happen if you follow the idea. I think you  are still reusing the previously found elements in the loop. Show your current code please.

Comment: @abhanan93 the `len(matches)` I think is what is killing it, can you try with the `while True` and try/except as I've posted? Thanks.

Comment: I tried your code and I think this is what was killing it. :) It worked, thanks a lot. :) I think the problem was that I was not creating a new array after every loop cycle.